# EOF error python

Tags: python, python-2.7, eof

I am writing a simple code in Python and getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 4, in 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

My code is:

```
inp = [""]
i=0
while i==0:
    answer = raw_input("")
    if answer!="":
        inp.append(answer)
    else:
        break

for item in inp:
    if item=="42":
        break
    else:
        print item

print ""
```

Comment: When did you receive this error? I can produce it with `python2 prog.py < /dev/null` ... when I enter text and or blank lines, it works as guessed (by reading the code). Do you want to shield against EOFError or do you want to understand why it is happeneing?

Comment: How are you running your script? There are [quite many answers regarding this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+raw_input+eoferror) already here, so perhaps you should read some of them first.

Comment: My code is also working good on Codeacdemy.com compiler but on Ideone.com, it is giving this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to read and understand this answer (to help you in your journey to Python knowledge):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
"""Short description what this module does."""
from __future__ import print_function


inp = []
while True:
    try:
        answer = raw_input("")  # in python v3 use input instead
    except EOFError as e:
        print("Ignored:", e)
        answer = None
    if answer:
        inp.append(answer)
    else:
        break

for item in inp:
    if item == "42":
        break
    else:
        print(item)

print()
```

It is only a first step in trying a more readable style of coding.

Next would be for sure trying the original Python tutorial at python.org ...

The call of above script stored in `prog.py`:

```
$> python2 prog.py < /dev/null
```

which makes the program read from `/dev/null` as input does not cause anymore this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 5, in <module>
    answer = raw_input("")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

but instead:

```
Ignored: EOF when reading a line
[]
```

if you want to simply not print out the `Ignored ...` line, and know that it is ok to silently ignore, you could rewrite that except line/block into

```
except EOFError:
    answer = None
```

Comment: thank you very much. Okay, 1 last time: So you are saying that for online compilers as ideone.com, we have to replace all of the raw_inputs by: those try and catches and please tell me why that is happening only in online interpreters like ideone but there is no problem with my original code at other interpreters